# Why does my indoor blower shut down 5 min after when I turn to heat mode?

Tags: hvac, thermostat, pump, heat, blower

I have a Tempstar Heat pump system and starting this year I went to heat mode.  Heat pump comes on along with the indoor blower.  5 min later the indoor blower will turn off but heat pump remains running.  System has an ECM indoor blow which I have replaced.  Replaced fan relay and board, replaced thermostat and heat pump control board.  The only thing left to replace is the electric heat kit.  Cooling mode works fine.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Model numbers of all items would be helpful.

Comment: What troubleshooting did you do before you started unloading the parts cannon at this heat pump?

Comment: When you say the heat pump remains running, do you mean the fan in the outdoor unit, the compressor, or both remain running?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  Both the outdoor fan and compressor remain running.  The indoor fan shuts off 5 min later.

Comment: The indoor air handler model is Tempstar (INTERNATIONAL COMFORT PRODUCTS) FEM4X1800BL2.

Comment: I don't have the Outdoor model on me but the schematic # is 339697-101 rev.B.  I try' d to attach picture but It wouldn't let me.  I'm thinking of bypassing the thermostat but have a question.  Do I connect only red and white at thermostat or do I need to add green with them?